# Renci.SshNet on background worker

Tags: c#, .net, ssh.net

I'm using Renci.SshNet to connect to a server via ssh.

```
using (var client = new SshClient("server.com", "", ""))
        {
            client.Connect();

            var cmd = client.CreateCommand("do soemthing");
            var result = cmd.Execute();

            statusWindow.Items.Add(result);

            var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.ExtendedOutputStream);

            using (StringReader readerIt = new StringReader(reader.ReadToEnd()))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = readerIt.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    statusWindow.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }

            client.Disconnect();

        }
```

It works fine, but when attempting to add this code to a background worker I am getting the following error;

> An exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced

Here is the background worker code;

```
public void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_Changed);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        using (var client = new SshClient("server.com", "", ""))
        {
            client.Connect();

            var cmd = client.CreateCommand("do soemthing");
            var result = cmd.Execute();

            statusWindow.Items.Add(result);

            var reader = new StreamReader(cmd.ExtendedOutputStream);

            using (StringReader readerIt = new StringReader(reader.ReadToEnd()))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = readerIt.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    statusWindow.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }

            client.Disconnect();

        }

    }
```

It raises the exception on the client.Connect();

Is there a simple reason why this may be the case?

**EDIT: I'm at a complete loss as to why this is the case, any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: I've just ran your code (swapping out the server address, username and password for my own of course) and had no trouble connecting.  Just out of curiosity, what happens if you run this in another thread?

Comment: It produces an exception as stated when I run on another tread.
Did you run using the background worker code?

Comment: Yes I used the background worker code with no issue.. I'm not sure why you'd get an exception just by running on a separate thread.. are you connecting to the ssh server anywhere else in the code? Qhat happens if you run a local ssh server and try connect to that via background worker?